# Pandas calculating age from a date

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I really need help with this one.  My previous post was very bad and unclear - I'm sorry - I wish I could delete but hopefully this one will be better.

I need to calculate the age based off of a date (see ANALYZE section and FINAL OUTCOME SECTION).

#### ORIGINAL DATA SET

```
"JOLIE", 09091959,02051983
"PORTMAN",02111979,01272002
"MOORE", 01281975,01182009
"BEST", 04081973,07022008
"MONROE", 04161957,11231979
```

#### LOAD DATA

```
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

columns = ['lname','dob','scd_csr_mdy']

raw_data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\davidlopez\Desktop\Folders\Standard Reports\HR Reports\eeprofil  \eeprofil.txt',` 
                       names=columns, parse_dates = ['dob','scd_csr_mdy'})

df1 = raw_data

In [1]: df1
Out [1]:

         lname          dob          scd_csr_mdy
    0    JOLIE          09091959     02051983
    1    PORTMAN        02111979     01272002
    2    MOORE          01281975     01182009
    3    BEST           04081973     07022008
    4    MONROE         04161957     11231979
```

#### ANALYZE

I tried doing the following but received an error:

```
now = datetime.now()
df1['age'] = now - df1['dob']
```

But I received the the error:

```
TypeError:  unsported operant type(S) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'
```

#### FINAL OUTCOME

```
     lname          dob          scd_csr_mdy    DOB_AGE     SCD_AGE
0    JOLIE          09091959     02051983       55          32
1    PORTMAN        02111979     01272002       36          13
2    MOORE          01281975     01182009       40          6
3    BEST           04081973     07022008       42          6
4    MONROE         04161957     11231979       58          35
```

Any suggestions.....?

Comment: Which is the output of `type(df1['dob'])`?

Comment: I guess it is a string, as the output of the `TypeError` indicates

Comment: dtype(['dob']) is 'o'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert string to datetime with format

```
df1['age'] = now - datetime.strptime(df1['dob'], "%m%d%Y")
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert the dob column from string to a datetime object

```
df1['dob'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['dob'])
now = datetime.now()    
df1['age'] = now - df1['dob']
```

Comment: This gave me the same error  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'

Comment: can you check pandas version using this: pd.__version__

Comment: pd.__version__  0.13.1

Comment: hmm, not sure what is happening. the code does seem to be working at my end. It seems like it has to do something with the csv. When I read in your dataframe using pd.read_clipboard() i.e. by copying the dataframe first, and then running the command; the datetime stuff does work for me

Answer (score 1):

if there's not too many entries, you can just do something like:

```
df['dob'] = df.dob.apply(lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d[-4:] + d[:4]))
now - df.dob
```